# How to make a link to add a filter list to uBlock Origin?

Tags: html, hyperlink, adblock, ublock-origin

[EasyList](https://easylist.to/) has "add it to your ad blocker" links for their various filter lists. When I click on them, my content blocker browser extension prompts me to add the filter list from EasyList. The EasyList website uses links to the `subscribe.adblockplus.org` domain (which doesn't actually resolve) to accomplish this. I want to make a link for people to easily be able to add *my* filter list to their content blocker (uBlock Origin in particular).

I've tried using the same link as EasyList, but uBlock Origin doesn't seem to be intercepting navigations to the magical `subscribe.adblockplus.org` domain, so I just get a "Server Not Found" error. How can I properly construct such a link?

Comment: When you have uBO installed, right-clicking on a `subscribe.adblockplus.org` link adds a _Subscribe to list..._ entry in the context menu, regardless of where the page containing the link is hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uBlock Origin only allows subscribe URLs on a [hardcoded list of domains](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/d0dbc27c025b894bdc5cf32d501a1aaf36725b07/platform/firefox/manifest.json#L60). `https://*.github.io/*` is on that list, so you can use a [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) site to host the page with the URL. (alternatively, you could just ask to be added to the list)

On an allowed domain, you can make a link to add a filter list like `https://subscribe.adblockplus.org/?location=[list URL]&title=[filter list title]` (where the URL and title are be URL-encoded), and clicking the link will prompt the user to add the filter list.

Comment: tried to use your instruction like this  [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/u2x5evpq/) not working. Any suggestion ?